# AWS: describe-images outputs nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami

When I run

```
aws ec2 describe-images
```

on one EC2 machine, I get no results at all, not even an empty response.
However, when I run the same command with the same IAM user on another machine, I get the expected responses. My IAM user has AmazonEC2FullAccess, which includes DescribeImages.

I have tried rebooting the machine, aws configure, and updating all packages, and nothing has changed this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using the --debug option, I saw that this was a MemoryError.

As the command was running on a t2.nano instance, upgrading to a t2.micro solved this issue.